# Changing Pecl installation directory

Tags: linux, installation, pear, pecl, gearman

Hi i'm having trouble with pecl installation, the problem i'm having is i'm installing [gearman](http://gearman.org/) , and i'm now at the stage of installation of the pecl PHP extension.

it should be a simple as executing the command :

```
$ sudo pecl install gearman
```

the installation was successfull and I could even test a php containing

```
<?php
echo "Gearman version: " . gearman_version() . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

executing it in CLI php using :

```
$ php gearman_version.php
```

does the trick. Unfortunately I am using a stack. [lappstack](https://bitnami.com/stack/lapp) to be precise, and I have a separate php in the installation of my lappstack which is in :

```
/home/userName/lappstack-5.4.34-0/php
```

where php/etc contains my **php.ini** for web use.

now, going back to the pecl installation of gearman, executing the **pecl install gearman**
results to gearman being installed in a separate php5 installation, and the **gearman.so** is installed in :

```
/usr/lib/php5/20121212/gearman.so
```

which, ideally, the gearman.so should be contained in :

```
/home/userName/lappstack-5.4.34-0/php/lib/php/extensions/gearman.so
```

like all my other extensions.

which actually results to the application not being able to use the gearman extension. And the php.ini that is being pointed to, to use gearman is actually the ones in :

```
/etc/php5/cli
```

and

```
/etc/php5/apache2
```

I need help, I'm really in the process of getting haywired in my installations. Thanks !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can see the configured directories with

```
$ pear config-show
```

To change the directories, e.g. `php_dir`, use `config-set`:

```
$ pear config-set php_dir /path/to/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You searching for param "ext_dir".
You can show current PECL installation directory with:

```
pear config-show | grep "ext_dir"
```