# Installing PHP imagick through PECL on Mac

Tags: php, macos, imagick, pecl

I'm trying to get the php imagick extension installed on a Mac with High Sierra 10.13.5.

I have PHP 7.2 installed through brew and PEAR 1.10.5 installed. When trying to install imagick using `sudo pecl install imagick` I get:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_shared.h'
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/imagick
```

It looks like I'm hitting the Mac permissions where the install directory should be in `/usr/local` but I cant figure out how to change it. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584599/changing-pecl-installation-directory)**, one of the answers may be pertinent to your issue.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529784/2836621

Comment: I've looked at `show-config` and changed all directories pointing to `/usr` to `/usr/local` but it doesn't seem to have helped anything. It's still trying to copy the header file to `/usr/include`

Comment: For a reference: I had the same issue running pecl install xdebug, got it unexpectedly fixed running the same command for the second time (without sudo both times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I needed PHP 7.1 not 7.2 but I still had the same problem.

Not sure if all of the steps I took were necessary but here's how I got around it:

- Get the current php extensions directory from running `php-config`
- Copy everything from that directory (in my case `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303)` to the equivalent in `/usr/local` so in my case to `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303`
- Update the php.ini and set the `extensions_dir` to the new directory in `/usr/local`
- Go to the build directory from pecl error and find the imagick tgz
- Extract this and enter the created directory
- As root:

  - run `./phpize`
  - run `./configure`
  - run `make`
  - Edit the makefile and change the include directory to the `/usr/local` equivalent.
  - run `make install`
- Edit the php.ini and add `imagick.so` to the extensions section

It seems to be working for me now but this probably isn't the easiest way to go about getting it installed.